# How the actions work in BuddyPress?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am working with BuddyPress; and, there are many actions, such as: `do_action('bp_before_wrapper')`, `do_action( 'bp_before_bodywrap' )`, `do_action( 'bp_before_container' )`...; bu,  I didn't find where define such actions.

Are they default actions in BuddyPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`do_action` is a WordPress call. There may be actions hooked to a do_action or it may just be there so developers can call it if they want.

For example `do_action( 'bp_before_container' );` is not hooked to anything, but you could write a function that hooks to it.

```
function snail_content() {
    echo 'I am a snail';
}
add_action('bp_before_container', 'snail_content' );
```

[Read the WP codex re do_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action).

btw - `do_action( 'bp_before_container' );` is in bp-themes which is deprecated. Use the files in bp-templates.

Comment: Thank you, Shane, it is quite helpful.